# Why my Java Process takes 16G Virtual Memory as soon as I start it

Tags: java, process, java-native-interface

I am just testing some JNI calls with a simple stand alone java program on a 16-core CPU. I am using 64-bit JVM & OS is Linux AS5. But, as soon as I start my test program with 64-bit c++ libraries, I see that the 'SIZE' column shows 16G. The top command output is something like this:

```
  PID  PSID USERNAME   THR PRI NICE  SIZE   RES STATE   TIME     CPU COMMAND
  3505 31483 xxxxxxx    23  16    0   16G  215M sleep   0:02   0.00% java
```

I understand that my heap is ok, but JNI memory can increase the process size, but I am confused as to why it starts with 16G - SIZE, which I believe is the Virtual Memory size? Is it really taking that much memory? Should I be concerned with it?

Comment: You're showing us a process with 27.2 hours of CPU time. This isn't a snapshot from "as soon as you start your test program".

Comment: Thanks Gabe. I just updated my question with the correct snapshot, with 2sec uptime.

Comment: Virtual address space is nearly free, as you can see your process is *currently* only occupying 215 megabytes. What is the value of the `-Xms` or any other command line options to the JVM?

Answer (score 0):

Odd, but it could be that your JNI calls are either somehow rapidly leaking memory or allocating a number of massive chunks of memory. What command line are you using to start the JVM, and what is your JNI code doing?

Comment: The test creates a native object by passing roughly 20MB xml, and then destorys it. It does this in a loop 10000 times. But in 2sec, may be it generally does <10 times.

Comment: I start the prgram with:  java -Djava.library.path=<libraries for JNI code> MyTest <arguments>, My classpath has a boat load of jars though. I guess that shouldn't matter.

Comment: Well, if it is parsing and retaining anything close to 20MB each pass through then you might not be properly releasing the memory.

Answer (score 0):

The comment by Greg Hewgill basically says it all: You're using only 215 MB of real memory. On my machine a nothing-doing Java process without any VM arguments gets 8 GB. You've got four times as many cores, so starting with twice as much memory makes sense to me.

As this number uses nothing but the virtual address space, which is something like 2**48 B or maybe 2**64 B, it's actually free. You could use `-mx1G` in order to limit the memory to 1 GB, but note that it is a hard limit and you'll get an OOME when the process needs more.